# NOMCAR in SAS equivalent to survey package in R

Tags: sas, survey

I have colleagues that use NOMCAR to compute variance estimation in complex survey data for SAS in domain analyses.  What would the comparable method be to do this in R.  Is this the default behavior, or do you have to specify that you are subsetting on the non-missing cases in addition to the other subset of interest.

For example would the code below be equivalent to NOMCAR if "nomiss" is an indicator of missing cases?

`subset(design.FST,nomiss & RIAGENDR == "Female" & RIDAGEYR >= 45)`

Comment: Since this is a question about R, you should probably tag it with that.  Also since many R users don't know SAS, you should probably update you question to explain what you're trying to do.  People won't know what NOMCAR does.